# What is the best way to create 301 redirects for removing a specific folder from URLs in .htaccess while maintaining existing rewrite rules?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I need to do 301 redirects from `xyz.com/folder/post-slug` to `xyz.com/post-slug` through `.htaccess` and want to keep both rewrite rules.

The aim is that the url will work with `/folder/` and without it.

This is the existing rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^folder/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ post-details.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

I tried to keep the existing one and added another one like this:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ post-details.php?url=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ post-details.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

but it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" exactly? Where is the `.htaccess` file? is `/folder` a physical filesystem directory? It looks like what you've posted should "work". (Although serving the same content from 2 URLs is not good for SEO, which is presumably why you want to implement a 301 redirect.) To confirm, you are linking internally to URLs _without_ the `/folder` prefix?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Rewrites + canonicals:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(?:folder/)?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ post-details.php?url=$1 [DPI,QSA,NC,L]
   ```

   Set the canonical meta tag for both `your.example/folder/post-slug` and `your.example/post-slug` to `your.example/post-slug`.
   Stop linking to the old URL, the new URL is what people will use and what search engines will see.
   Pro: good for SEO. Con: could break relative links that expect the page to be located at the new URL.
2. Redirect + rewrite:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^folder/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ https://your.example/$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ post-details.php?url=$1 [DPI,QSA,NC,L]
   ```

   Both users and search engines will be sent to the new URL.
   Pro: no need to do canonical tag. Con: wastes a round trip to your server, so not as good for SEO.

---

Note that I've added the `DPI` and `QSA` [flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) to the rewrites, because they are almost always required to avoid recursive internal redirect problems.